# Heroku App (play) working fine locally, then not saving to database on server

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, ebean

On Heroku using Play V2. Everything works fine when tested locally, but then when I deploy to Heroku and attempt to save to a PostgreSQL database I get the following error.

In my Procfile I have this.

```
web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Here are my Heroku Error Logs:

```
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval]]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: ! @6a0gdoh95 - Internal server error, for request [POST /users] ->
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.a

2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: [error] application - 
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:63) [play_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:61) [play_2.9.1-2.0.jar:2.0]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.loadMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:163) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.nextId(BeanDescriptor.java:1218) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.getMoreIds(SequenceIdGenerator.java:213) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:617) [akka-actor-2.0.jar:2.0]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.setIdGenValue(DefaultPersister.java:1304) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:179) [akka-actor-2.0.jar:2.0]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:290) [akka-actor-2.0.jar:2.0]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SequenceIdGenerator.nextId(SequenceIdGenerator.java:118) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.persist.DefaultPersister.insert(DefaultPersister.java:403) ~[ebean-2.7.3.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1810) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2077) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "user_seq" does not exist
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:498) ~[postgresql-8.4-702.jdbc4.jar:na]
```

Comment: Are you sure the tables are being created in the schema?  It looks like it can't find the next auto increment id to do an insert.  Is there anyway you can show your table structure and models?  Specifically the user model and table description.

Comment: Ebean created a 1.sql that is supposed to run, is there a way I can see if it did run, or at least run it manually?

Comment: Can you see if you can recreate the problem by modifying this example app: https://github.com/jamesward/play2bars-java  (That example works for me in it's current state on Heroku.)

Comment: Fixed...perhaps. Apparently in PostgreSQL you can't have a table called user. Ebeans was creating one, when I manually changed the table name, everything seemed to work!

Comment: I've run into that as well!  I think the newer version of Postgres on Heroku doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Actually you can have a table called "user" but because "user" is a reserved word you should probably quote it.  That Netbeans is not quoting tables in this case is likely the problem

Answer (score 2):

`2012-04-03T18:16:05+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "user_seq" does not exist`

Seems to indicate that your database is missing some tables. Make sure that your schema is correct. You can get a console to your DB using `heroku pg:psql`.

A good practice is setting up postgres locally from scratch and make sure that all of the steps to do so are automated by your application or scripts so that it is more difficult to forget things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have described the ID column like below and passed the error.

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "UserSequence", sequenceName = "\"USER_SEQ\"", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "UserSequence")
@Column(name = "\"USER_ID\"")
Long userId;
```