# [PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval]

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

i am getting this error while trying to save data into model in db.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
   @Required
   public String name; 
   @Email
   public String email; 
   @Required @MaxLength(value=10)
   public String username;
   @Required @MinLength(value=4)
   public String password;
   @Id 
   public int id;
}
```

this is my Class.

this is the error while i am trying to save the model into db.

[image]

i will appreciate any effort for help! many thanks.

EDIT: table structure is here
[image]

Comment: Please show your table structure (sql file which creates tables). And tell us on what db you're working, because, if it is on MySQL, it does not support sequences.

Comment: i added my table structure, please see update

Comment: did you use ebean to generate your tables?

Comment: yeah, it generated itself. but my suspect is that i have also an ID of my class. should i delete this as Ebean will create an ID automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999107/heroku-app-play-working-fine-locally-then-not-saving-to-database-on-server

Comment: thanks, Nico, i solved the problem by hardcoding the ID value and putting the @GeneratedValue annotation... now it is working like anything :D..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think with ebean you have to physically name and annotate your id. You may also have to tell it the name of the backing sequencer as well (I dont remember). [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) shows how to do it.

Comment: John, thanks alot! that was the point. Great Stackoverflower! ;)

Comment: This solution also worked for me (Play 2.0.4). The key was adding this annotation to my User model: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_id_seq")`. I dunno if Play isn't identifying the sequence correctly or what, but it works now. Frustrating.

Comment: I also had to define the sequence, otherwise Hibernate would tell me it doesn't know about users_id_seq: `@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_gen_name", sequenceName="task_seq") @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_gen_name") @Id public Long id;`

Comment: These example worked for me except I had to add my schema: sequenceName="myschema.my_seq" A simple thing, but easy to miss. It is mentioned in the code in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table", schema = "schema")
public class Bean extends Model{

   @Id
   @Column(name = "idcolumn")
   @SequenceGenerator(name="gen", sequenceName="schema.table_idcolumn_seq",allocationSize=1) 
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen")
   private int id;
}
```

When using the SequenceGenerator, please mind this bug in Hibernate: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7232

It forces you to write the schema directly into the sequenceName instead of using the schema field in the SequenceGenerator annotation.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on class annotation:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_NAME", sequenceName = "PST_BUSINESS.S_BUSINESS_DOMAIN")
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_BUSINESS_DOMAIN", schema = "PST_BUSINESS")
public class PstBusinessDomain extends PstAbstractBaseMappedEntity {
```

As Leo said, this strategy works for annotation in the field and also in the class.