# PersistenceException: Error getting sequence nextval

Tags: java, sql, playframework-2.0

Again the same problem! The exception comes if I annotate the ID with @Id.

```
@ForeignKey(name = "User") 
public String He;
@ForeignKey(name = "User") 
public String Him;
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
public int f_id;
```

But if I annotate some other String attribute, the error goes away. What can be the problem, can anyone help me pls?

What is the "evolutionsplugin=disabled" in conf file? Isn't it causing the issue?

Comment: i solved it in an informal way: i created another String attribute which i marked as primary key thru @Id and this is now working. but my question is still open why it is not working on INTEGER ID.. that would be perfect way of doing my job actually..

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260757/persistenceexception-error-getting-sequence-nextval.

Comment: yeah thanks, that was my own post. it is working now anyway.. i think i have to read the jdbc driver + h2 + persistence books in peace..

Comment: Heh. My bad. Just browsed it.

Comment: try using an `Integer` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Okay, i will try. what i did now is i chose another key as primary key and now all ids are 0. which is more than worse.